# Не работает простой сервлет

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MarketPlaceServlets</groupId>
    <artifactId>MarketPlaceServlets</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MarketPlaceServlets Maven MarketPlaceServlets</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>MarketPlaceServlets</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8888</port>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

web.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>

    <display-name>testServlet</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.epam.marketPlaceServets.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

TestServlet

```
    package org.epam.marketPlaceServets;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/test").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

при переходе по http://localhost:8888 успешно открывает стартовую страницу.

при переходе по http://localhost:8888/test  - 404

Comment: `<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>` попробуйте добавить

Comment: если я добавляю это то пишет 500 ошибку даже при  http://localhost:8888

Comment: скорее всего `servlet-name` должны быть одинаковые в `servlet` и `servlet-mapping`.

Comment: Если так ничего и не заработает, то скажите и мы попытаемся решить проблему с помощью аннотаций в сервлете

Comment: В общем, удалил все, переписал заново и все заработало) Понятия не имею  в чем была проблема.